# Google Analytics - showing different revenue for same month viewed

Tags: google-analytics

When viewing - Acquisition>>>All Traffic>>>Source/Medium with organic traffic segment loaded with dates Jan 1 - Oct 31, with the revenue metric (line chart graph setting) while viewing by revenue per month, I get the total amount of organic revenue per month from Jan 1 - October 31st. Each month shows the total organic revenue.

However, If I change the date range to only show revenue for October 1st - 31st (note, nothing else is changed but removing Jan 1 - Sept 31), the total revenue for October doesn't match the October revenue when I view it from Jan 1 - October 31st. It is really odd and I don't understand why.

Does anyone have any insight on why the month of October shows different revenue when I set the dates for October 1st - 31st compared to Jan 1st - October 31st with each month's revenue isolated in the graph?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that it's a sampling issue, go into GA and look for the shield icon at the top of the report page. If it's any color other than green, hover over it to see what the sampling is. If that is the issue, the main way to get unsampled data is to use a smaller date range, or looking for 'unsample' tools.